# ¿Cómo insertar un array de objetos dentro de otro array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hola estoy empezando con reactjs y tengo esta duda que no he podido resolver, estoy creando un pequeño proyecto donde se reciben 3 datos del usuario, esos datos los guardo en un array de objetos y lo que necesito es que ese array de objetos se almacene en otro array automáticamente ósea un array bidimensional, espero me puedan ayudar lo agradecería mucho.

hice este pequeño ejemplo para explicarme mejor

```
import {useState} from "react"


export function PruevaDeDatos(){
    const [nombre,setNombre] = useState('')
    const [edad,setEdad] = useState(0)
    const [ciudad,setCiudad] = useState('')
    const [datos,setDatos] = useState([])
    const [datosBox,setDatosBox] = useState([])



    const objeto ={ 
        name:nombre,
        age:edad,
        country:ciudad,
    };

 const enviar = () =>{

    setDatos(datos.concat(objeto))
    setDatosBox(datosBox.concat(datos))
}

return(
    <>
    <form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault();}}>

        <label htmlFor="">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setNombre(e.target.value)}} /><br></br>
        <label htmlFor="">edad</label>
        <input type="number" onChange={(e)=>{setEdad(e.target.value)}} /><br/>
        <label htmlFor="">cuidad</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setCiudad(e.target.value)}}/>
        <hr/>
        <button onClick={enviar} >Enviar</button>
    </form>
    </>
)
}
```

Comment: buenas tardes, adjunta tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: No tengo código, tómelo como un ejercicio, tiene un array de objetos y debes crear una función que lo inserte en otro array. Como lo haría? :D

Comment: array1.push(array2)

Comment: lo intente pero me lanza el error de array.push is not a function, puse un ejemplo para que vea mejor lo que intento hacer.

Comment: probaste haciendo setDatosBox( [...datosBox, objeto] ) ? No estas usando Typescript en vez de Javascript no?

Comment: No no uso Typescript, y probe como tu dices pero aun no funciona, solo se agrega el objeto al array datosBox, y nesecito que el array datos este dentro de datosBox

Comment: osea queres que datosBox sea una copia del array datos? que cuando clickeo en "enviar" me actualize el array datos y ese array datos lo use para actualizar datosBox? perdon que pregunte tanto porque no se entiende que queres hacer, tambien hablas de array bidimensional, eso es una matrix osea un array al que hay que referenciar las posiciones con dos indices tipo myArray[2][5]

Comment: simplemente quiero hacer un array de arrays, se necesita especificar la posicion para crear un array bidimencional? o solo se necesita especificar cuando quieres buscar una posicion o iterarlo?, perdon si no me doy bien a entender soy algo nuevo en esto. pero pongamoslo asi, quiero que el array datos que tiene como elementos objetos con 3 propiedades, se concatene al array datosBox que seria el padre por asi decirlo jsjs, entonces datos seria un array dentro de datosBox

Comment: No entiendo bien qué es lo que quieres hacer, ¿quieres meterle a cada usuario el arreglo de ciudades o qué? ¿Qué buscas hacer especificamente? Y por último, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: No hay un arreglo ciudades, Lo que quiero hacer es hacer un array de arrays, siendo el arreglo "dataBase" el que contenga mas arreglos dentro, tipo asi dataBase = [[name:"carlos", age:23,country:"usa" ],[name:"Juan", age:33,country:"Panama"  ] ]

Comment: Perdon me equivoque en el nombre del arreglo, seria datosBox el que contendría el arreglo datos dentro

Comment: Creo que estas un poco confundido, **[[name:"carlos", age:23,country:"usa" ],[name:"Juan", age:33,country:"Panama" ] ]** no almacenas un array de esta manera `[name:"carlos", age:23,country:"usa" ]` ya que no poseen {clave: valor}, debes estar separados por coma [["name", "carlos", "age", 30]] es est lo que quieres??

Comment: Utilizas la variabe `datos` para algo mas? por que simplemente no añades lo elementos al datosBox?

Comment: Tienes razon cometi un error en el ejemplo olvide colocar las llaves de los objetos, esto es lo que quiero hacer: datosBox = [
        [{name:"carlos", age:23,country:"usa"}],
        [{name:"Juan", age:33,country:"Panama"}]
    ]

Comment: datosBox es el array que contentra dentro otros arrays con objetos dentro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que la estructura que deseas es la siguiente:

```
 [ [{OBJETO1}], [{OBJETO2}], [{OBJETO3}] ]
```

A la cual vas a acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
ARRAY-PADRE[POSISION_HIJO][POSISION-NIETO][PROPIEDAD DEL OBJETO]
```

No le veo sentido a utilizar la variable datos como contenedor intermedio si la variable `objeto` tiene tus datos:

Yo te propongo lo siguiente:

```
export default function App() {
  const [objeto, setObjeto] = useState({});
  const [datosBox, setDatosBox] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(datosBox);
  }, [datosBox]);

  const enviar = () => {
    setDatosBox([...datosBox, [objeto]]);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setObjeto({ ...objeto, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <label htmlFor="">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" onChange={handleChange} />
        <br></br>
        <label htmlFor="">edad</label>
        <input type="number" name="edad" onChange={handleChange} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="">cuidad</label>
        <input type="text" name="ciudad" onChange={handleChange} />
        <hr />
        <button onClick={enviar}>Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Explicación:

- Reemplazamos las variables de estado que tenias por input (que no esta mal), por un objeto en el cual vas a modificar cada propiedad en base al `name` del `input` y su valor con respecto al `value` del `input`
- La funcion `handleChange` va a ser la encargada de modificar dicho objeto
- Y en la funcion enviar actualizamos el array padre con lo que el ya tiene y le añadimos un array que contiene el objeto.

Dejando como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo el [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-svwf7f?file=src/App.js) para que revises el ejemplo de la respuesta.
Saludos.